# Как заставить метод on() вести себя как метод live()?

Tags: jquery

В новых версиях jQuery не поддерживается метод `live()`, основной особенностью которого является то, что он "заставляет" срабатывать обработчик для элементов DOM структуры, которые были добавлены или изменены посредством JavaScript.

В документации пишут следующее:

> Метод on() введен в jQuery-1.7, чтобы объединить три метода библиотеки, устанавливающие обработчики событий на элементы страницы: .bind(), .delegate(), .live(). Сами эти методы считаются теперь устаревшими, хотя еще поддерживаться. Установить обработчик, срабатывающий только один раз, по прежнему можно только с помощью отдельного метода .one().

А также:

> ...submit, keydown, keypress, keyup, error. Каждый из этих типов имеет одноименный метод, являющейся краткой формой метода on() . К примеру, использование click(handler) равнозначно on("click", handler).

Т.е. получается, что если элемент DOM изменился, то воздействовать на них после этого никак нельзя?

Вот конкретный пример, в старых версиях jQuery этот код прекрасно работал:

```
$('.comparechek').live('click', function() {
    var ProductId = $(this).attr('value');
    AjaxADD = 'action=ADD_TO_COMPARE_LIST&id=' + ProductId;
    $.post('/', AjaxADD);
    $(this).attr('class', 'comparechekUN');
});

$('.comparechekUN').live('click', function() {
  var ProductId = $(this).attr('value');
  AjaxADD = 'action=DELETE_FROM_COMPARE_LIST&id=' + ProductId;
  $.post('/', AjaxADD);
  $(this).attr('class', 'comparechek');
});
```

Т.е. по клику на `checkbox` отсылается один POST запрос, и у элемента меняется класс, при повторном клике отсылается другой POST запрос, и класс элемента становится прежний. Те же 2 функции, в которых `live()` заменён на `on()`, не работают, точнее первая срабатывает, а вторая - нет.

Как можно заставить работать `on()` как `live()`, или какой метод теперь применять в новом jQuery, если он не поддерживает `live()`?

Версия jQuery v1.11.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

все просто. делегируем клик на класс comparechek

```
$(document).on('click', '.comparechek', function() {
    // ваш код
});
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Тоже благодарна!!! Хоть и столько времени прошло, но вот только сейчас это для меня стало актуальным, и надо ж было в поисках набрести на эту страничку!

Comment: спс, мне также помогло! жалко конечно что .live удалили , с этим было проще логику понимать